# Stored procedure calling 2 values in parameter declaration

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure written like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_location_example(in_data_ID       IN VARCHAR2,
                                                  in_Location_name IN VARCHAR2)
 IS
  v_Location_ID NUMBER;
  v_data_id     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  lv_prog_name := 'PRoc_location_example';
  ln_step      := 1;
  SELECT Location_ID
    INTO v_Location_ID
    FROM random.client
   WHERE Location_name = in_Location_name;
   
 .....
END;
```

This procedure is getting 'NY ' passed in as an example for `in_location_name`. I want to pass in 'NY' and 'nj' to the `location_name`.

In other words the location name supports 2 name so which will be easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an expression with an `IN` operator such as

```
.. WHERE Location_name = in_Location_name AND in_Location_name IN ('NY','nj')
```

if case-sensitivity doesn't matter, then use

```
.. WHERE Location_name = in_Location_name AND REGEXP_LIKE(in_Location_name, 'Ny|nJ','i')
```

in order to restrict the parameters to those two values.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I can think of that would satisfy your question.

### Option #1: More Parameters

By adding more parameters you can use those parameters in your query for location IDs. If you are going to potentially more than 2 locations and don't want to keep having to add parameters, **Option #2** is probably a better choice.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_location_example (in_location_name1   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                                   in_location_name2   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
IS
    TYPE location_id_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

    v_location_ids   location_id_t;
BEGIN
    SELECT location_id
      BULK COLLECT INTO v_location_ids
      FROM (SELECT 101 AS location_id, 'NJ' AS location_name FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 102, 'NY' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 103, 'MA' FROM DUAL)
     WHERE location_name IN (in_location_name1, in_location_name2);

    FOR i IN 1 .. v_location_ids.COUNT
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ID #' || i || ': ' || v_location_ids (i));
    END LOOP;
END;
/

BEGIN
    Proc_location_example (in_location_name1 => 'NJ', in_location_name2 => 'NY');
END;
/
```

### Option #2: Table Type Parameter

By using a table as your parameter, you can pass an unlimited number of "location names". This does require you to use a pre-defined table type, but this solution is more flexible in the number of "parameters"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE location_name_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (2);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_location_example (in_locations location_name_t)
IS
    TYPE location_id_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

    v_location_ids   location_id_t;
BEGIN
    SELECT location_id
      BULK COLLECT INTO v_location_ids
      FROM (SELECT 101 AS location_id, 'NJ' AS location_name FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 102, 'NY' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 103, 'MA' FROM DUAL)
     WHERE location_name IN (select * from table(in_locations));

    FOR i IN 1 .. v_location_ids.COUNT
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ID #' || i || ': ' || v_location_ids (i));
    END LOOP;
END;
/

BEGIN
    Proc_location_example (in_locations => location_name_t('NJ','NY'));
END;
/
```